# Top-bar does not alert to reputation changes after bounty awarded

Tags: bug, top-bar

I noticed that the top-bar did not alert me with a green `+5` when [a question of mine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18049/has-any-prominent-theologian-ever-explained-why-jesus-let-a-thief-be-in-charge-o) was upvoted.

I suspect that is because I had just awarded a bounty<sup>1</sup> hence my rep went first `-100` and then `-95` after an upvote was cast. So perhaps this is why the `+5` was not detected?

<sub>1 The reason for the bounty can be found on [meta Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3283/the-advent-bounties-2013).</sub>